# RSA Public and private key authentication on command line/PHP

Tags: security, authentication

I've been asked to authenticate a public key received over an API via SSL using a POST method (Public key in header)

The server has the private key and I need to authenticate the person connecting to the API using these two files within a APIs PHP script and return a token if successful.

I need to be able to do this either from the Linux Cli (or through a PHP function). If its Cli I will run it through shell exec php command.

The keys were generated using 'ssh-keygen -t rsa' and no passphrase. A passphrase will be added later once testing is done

I am not having much luck in finding an answer on how to do this. I've only found solutions for SSH connections or encrypting files.

Thought possibly the php command "ssh2_auth_pubkey_file" would be suitable but this needs a connection resource when all I need to do is authenticate that the public key is the correct one for the private key.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Cheers
John

Comment: I believe `ssh-keygen -y -f private-key-file` should, after entering the passphrase, yield the same output as `cat public-key-file` if `private-key-file` matches `public-key-file`.

Comment: Cheers, I used this successfully.

Comment: Good! Please allow me to state my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh-keygen` offers a mechanism to compare private and public key files.

Let's say your public key is in `public_key_file` and the private key in `private_key_file`. Then doing

`ssh-keygen -y -f private_key_file`

will ask you for the passphrase, and then output something like

`ssh-rsa e9gwUnostzLTWF+djmzcMNNS/YcWjZR...`

whereas `cat public_key_file` will show

`ssh-rsa e9gwUnostzLTWF+djmzcMNNS/YcWjZR...` followed by a line containing `user@hostname`.

You could strip off the last line from the `cat` command and verify that is exactly equal to the output of the `ssh-keygen -y` command.